# Grab the second div after tag using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a website code like below:

```
CODE ABOVE
<div class="full">
   <div>
      <div> **<== WANT TO START GRABBING HERE **
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
      </div> **<== STOP GRABBING HERE **
   </div>
</div>
CODE BELOW
```

I'm trying to use regex in Python in order to get the entire content of the second `<div>` after the `<div class="full">` stopping after the div is closed, as indicated in the code above.

My question is: It's possible to do this in Python using Regex? And how to?

Comment: Why would you not simply parse the HTML?

Comment: Use XML parser (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)... Regex is basically line-based...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For html element selection `Beautiful Soup` is what you need, `@QHarr` answer should work Just check what encoding you are using.

But if you want Regex solution just make your string flat (no line break) than search for element:

```py
        import re

        html = """<div class="full">
           <div>
              <div> **<== WANT TO START GRABBING HERE **
                <div>CONTENT</div>
                <div>CONTENT</div>
                <div>CONTENT</div>
                <div>CONTENT</div>
              </div> **<== STOP GRABBING HERE **
           </div>
        </div>"""
        sep = 'xxxx****'   # dummy string to replace \n and put them back
        r = '<div class="full">[\s{0}]*<div>(.*)</div>[\s{0}]*</div>'.format(sep)
        # search will return first matching element.
        l = re.search(r, html.replace('\n',sep)).groups(0)[0]
        # findall will return all element matching the pattern if you have more than one use findall
        # l = re.findall(r, html.replace('\n',sep))[0]
        print(l.replace(sep, '\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case, try the following regex:

```
(<div>\s+){2}([\s\w</>]*?)(</div>\s+){2}
```

and then extract the needed group from it.

However, I'd suggest using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead, it's much easier and more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this with combination of [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) and [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) css selectors along with [child combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<div class="full">
   <div>
      <div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('.full > div > div'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm getting ```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable ```

Comment: Yes, I'm running on OnlineGDB exactly as you send.

Comment: it's that compiler as it doesn't seem to be able to select anything.

Comment: Tried in rextester and got ```SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file```

Comment: remove the **<== WANT TO START GRABBING HERE ** etc... See edit above. These tools are less forgiving. See https://rextester.com/live/SSO67358